Generate chained like string with enums and struct
I'm experimenting with proc-macro, the goal is that I can chain functions like a struct that contain fields of enums,
Look at the test, the response will be
permission::auth::moderator::execute::conditional
main.rs:
use ::enum_display::RbacBuilder;

#[derive(Debug, RbacBuilder)]
pub struct PermissionBuilder {
    #[enum_def(Object)]
    object: Option<Object>,
    #[enum_def(Subject)]
    subject: Option<Subject>,
    #[enum_def(Action)]
    action: Option<Action>,
    #[enum_def(Permission)]
    permission: Option<Permission>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Subject {
    User,
    Admin,
    Guest,
    Moderator,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Object {
    Auth,
    Role,
    Resource,
    Policy,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Action {
    Create,
    Read,
    Update,
    Delete,
    List,
    Execute,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Permission {
    Allow,
    Deny,
    Conditional,
}
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_permission() {
        let result = PermissionBuilder::new()
            .auth()
            .moderator() // New method from added enum variant
            .execute() // New method from added enum variant
            .conditional() // New method from added enum variant
            .finish();

        println!("perm: {:?}", result);
    }
}


my proc macro library (enum_display/src/lib.rs) look like this:
extern crate proc_macro;
extern crate proc_macro2;
extern crate quote;
extern crate syn;

use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use quote::{format_ident, quote};
use syn::{parse_macro_input, Data, DeriveInput, Fields, Type};

#[proc_macro_derive(RbacBuilder, attributes(enum_def))]
pub fn rbac_builder_derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let input = parse_macro_input!(input as DeriveInput);
    let name = input.ident;

    let mut methods = vec![];

    if let Data::Struct(data_struct) = &input.data {
        if let Fields::Named(fields_named) = &data_struct.fields {
            for field in fields_named.named.iter() {
                if let Some(ident) = &field.ident {
                    let ty = &field.ty;

                    // Extract the enum name and its variants
                    let enum_name = match ty {
                        Type::Path(type_path) => {
                            if let Some(segment) = type_path.path.segments.last() {
                                // Check if it's an Option<T>
                                if segment.ident == "Option" {
                                    if let syn::PathArguments::AngleBracketed(args) =
                                        &segment.arguments
                                    {
                                        if let Some(syn::GenericArgument::Type(Type::Path(
                                            inner_type_path,
                                        ))) = args.args.first()
                                        {
                                            if let Some(inner_segment) =
                                                inner_type_path.path.segments.last()
                                            {
                                                Some(inner_segment.ident.clone())
                                            } else {
                                                None
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            None
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        None
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Some(segment.ident.clone())
                                }
                            } else {
                                None
                            }
                        }
                        _ => None,
                    };

                    if let Some(enum_name) = enum_name {
                        eprintln!("Detected enum: {:?}", enum_name);

                        // Directly reference the enums instead of finding them in the AST
                        let enum_variants = get_enum_variants(&enum_name.to_string());

                        if let Some(variants) = enum_variants {
                            for variant in variants {
                                let method_name = format_ident!("{}", variant.to_lowercase());
                                let variant_ident = format_ident!("{}", variant);

                                methods.push(quote! {
                                    pub fn #method_name(mut self) -> Self {
                                        self.#ident = Some(#enum_name::#variant_ident);
                                        self
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        } else {
                            eprintln!("Enum definition not found for {:?}", enum_name);
                        }
                    } else {
                        eprintln!("Field type is not a recognized path: {:?}", ty);
                    }
                } else {
                    eprintln!("Field without an identifier");
                }
            }
        } else {
            eprintln!("Struct does not have named fields");
        }
    } else {
        eprintln!("Not a struct: {:?}", input.data);
    }

    let expanded = quote! {
        impl #name {
            pub fn new() -> Self {
                Self {
                    object: None,
                    subject: None,
                    action: None,
                    permission: None,
                }
            }

            #(#methods)*

            pub fn finish(self) -> String {
                format!(
                    "permission::{:?}::{:?}::{:?}::{:?}",
                    self.object.unwrap(),
                    self.subject.unwrap(),
                    self.action.unwrap(),
                    self.permission.unwrap()
                ).to_lowercase().replace("::", "::")
            }
        }
    };

    TokenStream::from(expanded)
}

fn get_enum_variants(enum_name: &str) -> Option<Vec<&'static str>> {
    match enum_name {
        "Subject" => Some(vec!["User", "Admin", "Guest", "Moderator"]),
        "Object" => Some(vec!["Auth", "Role", "Resource", "Policy"]),
        "Action" => Some(vec![
            "Create", "Read", "Update", "Delete", "List", "Execute",
        ]),
        "Permission" => Some(vec!["Allow", "Deny", "Conditional"]),
        _ => None,
    }
}


The problem here is that I cannot find a way to infer the enum values and must hardcode them in my library.
How I can get rid of the hardcoded lib.rs?

To be clear, your problem is specifically the get_enum_variants function? Then you'd have to pass that information to your proc macro somehow, either it has to be an function like macro that encompasses all enums or you have to #[derive(RbacBuilder)] on the sub enums as well and use that in your derived RbacBuilder for PermissionBuilder. Currently you only pass it the tokens of PermissionBuilder and those don't include any information on the sub enums.

@cafce25 ohhh i see, i will try that first

@cafce25 but, now i need to rebuild the entire macro RbacBuilder to also accept enum and not only struct correct?

Yes, a derive macro just on PermissionBuilder can not work dynamically on it's own, it needs further information that is not available.

@cafce25 i have tried to add a proc-macro that will collect the enums, but somehow proc-macro file cannot have constant or global variable to store those collected enums.

Naturally, the order in which derives is not specified. The derive on a enum might even not run at all and reuse a cached value. You can't rely on globals to pass your state, you'll have to use the RbacBuilder implepmentation from the generated code, not from the proc macro code.

Remember that you can have multiple impl blocks for the same struct. So I would go the other way: add a derive only for the enums, that takes the names of the struct and field as parameters and adds an impl block for the struct with the methods corresponding to the current enum.

Usage would look like that: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=974d8974b88c601ded60a2a5ac520db3

@Jmb Your solution is working! thank you, i will post the answer bellow

After i did try and error, I'm following @Jmb comment, which turn out working really well:
// lib.rs

extern crate proc_macro;
extern crate proc_macro2;
extern crate quote;
extern crate syn;

use proc_macro::TokenStream;
use proc_macro2::Span;
use quote::quote;
use quote::ToTokens;
use syn::{parse_macro_input, Attribute, DeriveInput, Ident};

#[proc_macro_derive(RbacEnum, attributes(enum_field))]
pub fn rbac_enum_derive(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
  let input = parse_macro_input!(input as DeriveInput);
  let name = &input.ident;

  // Extract the enum variants
  let data = match input.data {
    syn::Data::Enum(data) => data,
    _ => {
      return TokenStream::from(quote! {
          compile_error!("#[derive(RbacEnum)] can only be used with enums");
      })
    }
  };

  let field_name = match extract_field_name(&input.attrs) {
    Ok(field) => field,
    Err(err) => {
      return TokenStream::from(quote! {
          compile_error!(#err);
      })
    }
  };

  let mut methods = Vec::new();
  for variant in data.variants.iter() {
    let variant_name = &variant.ident;
    let method_name = Ident::new(
      &variant_name.to_string().to_lowercase(),
      variant_name.span(),
    );

    methods.push(quote! {
        impl #name {
            pub fn #method_name() -> Self {
                #name::#variant_name
            }
        }

        impl PermissionBuilder {
            pub fn #method_name(mut self) -> Self {
                self.#field_name = Some(#name::#variant_name);
                self
            }
        }
    });
  }

  let expanded = quote! {
      #(#methods)*
  };

  TokenStream::from(expanded)
}

fn extract_field_name(attrs: &[Attribute]) -> Result<Ident, String> {
  for attr in attrs {
    if attr.path.is_ident("enum_field") {
      if let Ok(meta) = attr.parse_meta() {
        if let syn::Meta::List(list) = meta {
          if let Some(syn::NestedMeta::Meta(syn::Meta::Path(path))) =
            list.nested.first()
          {
            let path_string = path.to_token_stream().to_string();
            let parts: Vec<&str> = path_string.split("::").collect();
            if parts.len() == 2 {
              let field_name = parts[1].trim();
              if !field_name.is_empty() {
                return Ok(Ident::new(field_name, Span::call_site()));
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  Err("Missing or invalid enum_field attribute".to_string())
}


the lib.rs now can infer the enums value and expand the methods using impl from #[enum_field(...)]
// main.rs

use ::enum_display::RbacEnum;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct PermissionBuilder {
  object: Option<Object>,
  subject: Option<Subject>,
  action: Option<Action>,
  permission: Option<Permission>,
}
impl PermissionBuilder {
  pub fn new() -> Self {
    Self {
      object: None,
      subject: None,
      action: None,
      permission: None,
    }
  }

  pub fn finish(self) -> String {
    format!(
      "permission::{:?}::{:?}::{:?}::{:?}",
      self.object.unwrap(),
      self.subject.unwrap(),
      self.action.unwrap(),
      self.permission.unwrap()
    )
    .to_lowercase()
    .replace("::", "::")
  }
}

#[derive(Debug, RbacEnum)]
#[enum_field(PermissionBuilder::subject)]
pub enum Subject {
  User,
  Admin,
  Guest,
  Moderator,
}

#[derive(Debug, RbacEnum)]
#[enum_field(PermissionBuilder::object)]
pub enum Object {
  Auth,
  Role,
  Resource,
  Policy,
}

#[derive(Debug, RbacEnum)]
#[enum_field(PermissionBuilder::action)]
pub enum Action {
  Create,
  Read,
  Update,
  Delete,
  List,
  Execute,
}

#[derive(Debug, RbacEnum)]
#[enum_field(PermissionBuilder::permission)]
pub enum Permission {
  Allow,
  Deny,
  Conditional,
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
  use super::*;

  #[test]
  fn test_permission() {
    let result = PermissionBuilder::new()
      .auth()
      .moderator() // New method from added enum variant
      .execute() // New method from added enum variant
      .conditional() // New method from added enum variant
      .finish();

    println!("perm: {:?}", result); // print: perm: "permission::auth::moderator::execute::conditional"
  }
}


to use it we can call the proc_macro RbacEnum derive with enum_field attributes.
which will target the struct PermissionBuilder because of enum_field attributes.
Thanks again @Jmb for leading the way, and @cafce25 for making me have faith in this experiments!
